# Two lists of favorite words

Tags: pattern, word-problem, english, knowledge, language

My great aunt Edith keeps this list of her favorite words tacked on the refrigerator:

> Atlas
>   Chance
>   Detail
>   Frost
>   Hand
>   Magnet
>   Orange
>   Ring
>   Sand
>   Tiger
>   Winter
>   Wolf

My great uncle Mark has this list of his favorites:

> Angel
>   Art
>   Bad
>   Boot
>   Gift
>   Hall
>   Kind
>   Mutter
>   Rat
>   Stern

Which one of them would like the word *Listen*?

Comment: both list are sorted....purposefully ?.....Also if it is to Listen then answer is always Great Aunt ;)

Comment: @user2408578: I don't think that the order of the words is important. But I'd say that the words in the lists were purposefully written with a capital letter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your

> great uncle Mark

likes the word "Listen". Here's why:

> All words can be English or German words. The words in Aunt Edith's list have the same meaning in German and in English. (Or there is at least one common meaning. "Ring" in German means a round band of metal, but not a call on the phone.) The words in Uncle Mark's list have a different meaning in English and German. "Gift", for example, means poison. And "Listen" means lists and has nothing to do with hearing.

Comment: This explanation does not fit for at least 'mist' and 'rock'.

Comment: @jarnbjo: Why not? (Hmm, not sure about the spoiler policy in comments.)

Comment: As you already said yourself: The same music style is called rock both in English an in German. 'Mist' can in German also have the meaning of 'fog', just as 'mist' in English.

Comment: The music style is called Rock, but it's essentially an English word. (But it's awkward that Jazz is in the aunt's list, which isn't really a German word, just a word that is _used_ in German, like Rock.) The traditional meaning of Rock is coat or skirt. I've never heard Mist to mean spray or fog in German. It might be a dialect word, though. (Mist means dung. It's also a rather mild swear word.)

Comment: Duden lists 'Mist' as a nautical term: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Mist_Nebel

Comment: My tabletop Duden has only one entry for Mist. (The nautical term is listed as very infrequent and states that it comes from English. Did you know that meaning before looking it up? I would have understood it in context, but i'd never heard it.) In the spirit of the puzzle, let's not draw too fine a line here. Especially the aunt's words are not ideal: Many of them are foreign terms (Orange, Magnet, Detail, Quiz) and the same meaning is often more of a similar meaning.

Comment: (Also: Once you see a pattern, you start trying to fit everything into it :-)

Comment: I was pretty sure that I had heard 'Mist' in that sense. That was why I checked my dictionary to be sure. But I also have much contact with sailing and boating people, I might have picked it up from them.

Comment: Well, I'm obviously not a boating person. Didn't know that usage. Now I do.

Comment: I admit I'm just a beginner in German. I will remove the controversial words mentioned in Mark's list. @MOehm, if you have better ideas for words in either list please feel free to edit.

Comment: there's a term for these, bw: `Cognates` vs `False Cognates`

Comment: @Luke: Well done, nice puzzle! (Although I might have had a slight edge in solving it.) I'm easy with the words you removed. If anything, my quibble is with some words in Edith's list: Quiz and Jazz are frequently used, but are really English words in disguise. Arm, Hand, Wind and Wolf might be good replacements, but run the risk that the list looks too Germanic. (But maybe that's a good hint.)

Comment: @DLeh: Isn't the meaning here a bit tighter than the meaning of cognate? The words have the same written representation. There are many cognates in English and German, but most are different. Some are homophones or near homophones, but differ in writing: house/Haus or fish/Fisch.

Comment: @MOehm According to wiki it's a cognate if it only has the same etymological origin, so I suppose. These are a more specific subset of cognates that are identically spelled.

Comment: @MOehm, I will update Edith's list with your suggestions.