# Two lists of favorite words 2!

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking, computer-science

This is inspired from Luke's [Two lists of favorite words](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15241/two-lists-of-favorite-words).

My aunt Sally keeps this list of her favorite words tacked on the refrigerator:

- Angel
- Art
- Atlas
- Bad
- Detail
- Hall
- Hand
- Mutter
- Rat
- Tiger
- Winter

My uncle Joe has this list of his favorites:

- Boot
- Chance
- Frost
- Gift
- Kind
- Magnet
- Orange
- Ring
- Sand
- Stern
- Wolf

Which one of them would like the word *Listen*?

Hint #1:

> Both my aunt and uncle had this word on their list:
>
> ---
>
> [image: a busy cat]

Hint #2:

> My aunt is British and my uncle is American.

Hint #3:

> My aunt and uncle wanted to seem up with the times:
>
> ---
>
> My aunt added "lol" 
>  My uncle added "brb"

Hint #4

> Don't look at the forest, but the trees.

Hint #5

> The two lists are mutually exclusive.

Hint #6

> I excluded the English tag very much on purpose

Note: No computer science knowledge is necessary to solve this, but thinking like one is helpful.

Comment: Fairly interesting to note: All the words on your uncle's list *apart from* 'Chance', 'Gift', and 'Magnet' all have a Middle English origin.

Comment: Interesting Mark :) Your train is headed in the wrong direction though.

Comment: I'm still thinking about this one... Any more hints?

Comment: @CodeNewbie Added a bunch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint 2 is confusing me, but all the other clues seem to fit the following rule:

> Substitute letters with their place in the alphabet (i.e. a->1, b->2, ... z->26) and sum. If the sum is odd, it can go on Aunt's list, if even it can go on Uncle's. BUT... Airplane (US spelling) gives a sum of 76, whereas the British Aeroplane has a sum of 87, so these seem the wrong way round by my rule.

Comment: Good work! Sorry for getting that hint backwards!

Comment: So, which one like the word Listen ?

Answer (score 3):

I think ...

> It has something to do with how some words are preferred in American English vs British English. Aunt Sally would use 'rat' (list word) while Uncle Joe would use 'mouse'. Likewise, Uncle Joe would say 'gift' and 'boot' (list words) while Aunt Sally would say 'present' and 'shoe'. For the first hint, it is not actually the same word on both lists, because Uncle Joe would use 'aeroplane' while Aunt Sally would use 'airplane'.
> By this logic, Uncle Joe would have 'listen' on his list, because the British prefer to use the phrase 'listen to me' while the Americans prefer 'hear me out' for the same activity.

*I am not entirely sure about my answer because I only managed to explain a few words, but it fits very well with the hint, so I thought I'd give it a shot.*

Comment: You were on the right track....kind of, I intentionally left the "English" tag out of the question.

Comment: _were on the right track_?

Comment: The last sentence of your first paragraph was the right track.